# configure: error: Cannot find libtidy

Tags: php, rhel6, configuration

I want to build PHP 5.3.9 on RHEL 6.2 with Tidy support. I get this message:

```
configure: error: Cannot find libtidy
```

So I try to install libtidy:

```
yum install libtidy libtidy-devel
```

but libtidy-devel is not available:

```
Package libtidy-0.99.0-19.20070615.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package libtidy-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

Shouldn't libtidy-devel be in Red Hat's repo? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `rhel-source` repo enabled in `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory. By default it might not be and `libtidy-devel` will come from that repo.

Comment: It worked after I enabled [rhel-6-server-optional-rpms] in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*libtidy-devel* is [available](https://rhn.redhat.com/network/software/packages/name_overview.pxt?package_name=libtidy-devel&archIdList=520&archLabelList=x86_64&search_subscribed_channels=) in the repos.

Maybe you're missing the required channel?

```
RHEL Server Optional (v. 6 64-bit x86_64)
RHEL Server Optional (v. 6 for 32-bit x86)
```